# How to force a connection to a site through Chrome (or any other browser's) "Your connection is not private" screen

Tags: networking, google-chrome, connection, brute-force

Trying to connect to a site for work but I keep getting a "your connection is not private" screen that won't allow me to bypass it by the usual drop down and continue to site. I 1000% do not care at this point if someone steals all of my information I just want to tell chrome that I accept any risk and want to connect. Wildly Frustrating.

Error says"

> [site name] normally uses encryption to protect your information. When
> Chrome tried to connect to [site name] this time, the website sent
> back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an
> attacker is trying to pretend to be [site name], or a Wi-Fi sign-in
> screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still
> secure because Chrome stopped the connection before any data was
> exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit [site name] right now because the website uses HSTS.
> Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will
> probably work later.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a way to bypass this error, it's a pretty annoying way but it should work.

Click anywhere in Chrome window where you see the error, and type `thisisunsafe` (type it out, not Copy/Paste, despite not seeing any feedback while typing) and when done it should refresh and allow you to access the site.

(To note, this bypass-phrase may change in the future. It used to be `badidea` until the Chrome team silently changed it.)

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: It seems to be intentionally NOT documented/posted anywhere by the Chrome team, but you can see it in the code https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js "This allows errors to be skippped by typing a secret phrase into the page" (it's base64 encoded), and see here the commit where they changed it from ```badidea``` https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d8fc089b62cd4f8d907acff6fb3f5ff58f168697 and you can see that they aren't trying it to be popular...